# Need help understanding how libchan works

Tags: go, libchan

I'm trying to use the [libchan](https://github.com/docker/libchan/) library to send messages between machines using a go channel-like transport.

From what I've gathered, the rough idea is this:

1. You have a SPDY client that sends a serialized command object to an address over tcp. This command object contains a libchan channel called a `Pipe` that the response is sent through.
2. When the server receives an incoming connection, it waits for a command object. When it gets one, it sends a response through the `Pipe` contained in the object.

Here's my point of confusion. For a channel to persist between two machines, they'd have to share memory or atleast share an abstraction that connects the two of them. From my grokking of the libchan codebase, I have no idea how this could be possible.

Here's a snippet from the example in the repo:

```
// client

    receiver, remoteSender := libchan.Pipe()
    command := &RemoteCommand{
        Cmd:        os.Args[1],
        Args:       os.Args[2:],
        Stdin:      os.Stdin,
        Stdout:     os.Stdout,
        Stderr:     os.Stderr,
        StatusChan: remoteSender,
    }

    err = sender.Send(command)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = receiver.Receive(response)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    os.Exit(response.Status)
```

and the server:

```
// server
t := spdy.NewTransport(p)

        go func() {
            for {
                receiver, err := t.WaitReceiveChannel()
                if err != nil {
                    log.Print("receiver error")
                    log.Print(err)
                    break
                }
                log.Print("about to spawn receive proc")
                go func() {
                    for {
                        command := &RemoteReceivedCommand{}
                        err := receiver.Receive(command)
                        returnResult := &CommandResponse{}
                        if res != nil {
                            if exiterr, ok := res.(*exec.ExitError); ok {
                                returnResult.Status = exiterr.Sys(). 
                              (syscall.WaitStatus).ExitStatus()
                            } else {
                                log.Print("res")
                                log.Print(res)
                                returnResult.Status = 10
                            }
                        }
                        err = command.StatusChan.Send(returnResult)
```

The point I'm trying to hone in is here:

```
libchan.Pipe()
```

According to the source, this returns a channel. One reference is kept on the client, and the other is sent to the server. This channel is then used to pipe values from the latter to the former. How does this actually work in practice?

Full code for [client](https://github.com/docker/libchan/blob/0328dcec840a0659448faf08af087135fffb7fde/examples/rexec/client.go) and [server](https://github.com/docker/libchan/blob/0328dcec840a0659448faf08af087135fffb7fde/examples/rexec/rexec_server/server.go)

Answer (score 0):

First, it's good to know that all `Pipe()` does is make a channel and return the in-memory sender/receiver pair.

From [`inmem.go`](https://github.com/docker/libchan/blob/0328dcec840a0659448faf08af087135fffb7fde/inmem.go#L74):

```
// Pipe returns an inmemory Sender/Receiver pair.
func Pipe() (Receiver, Sender) {
    c := make(chan interface{})
    return pReceiver(c), pSender(c)
}
```

Then you can look in [`inmem_test.go`](https://github.com/docker/libchan/blob/0328dcec840a0659448faf08af087135fffb7fde/inmem_test.go) for a simple end-to-end example.

[This struct](https://github.com/docker/libchan/blob/0328dcec840a0659448faf08af087135fffb7fde/inmem_test.go#L14) is the equivalent of `RemoteCommand` from the demo.

```
type InMemMessage struct {
    Data   string
    Stream io.ReadWriteCloser
    Ret    Sender
}
```

In `TestInmemRetPipe()`, a simple client and server are created.

[The client](https://github.com/docker/libchan/blob/0328dcec840a0659448faf08af087135fffb7fde/inmem_test.go#L21) creates a local sender/receiver pair using `Pipe()`, while [the server](https://github.com/docker/libchan/blob/0328dcec840a0659448faf08af087135fffb7fde/inmem_test.go#L40) simply uses the [`libchan.Sender` interface](https://github.com/docker/libchan/blob/0328dcec840a0659448faf08af087135fffb7fde/libchan.go#L18) in the `InMemMessage` struct.

Note that the client and server are functions which receive a `Sender` or `Receiver` as an argument respectively. More on this in the next code snippet.

```
func TestInmemRetPipe(t *testing.T) {
    client := func(t *testing.T, w Sender) {
        ret, retPipe := Pipe()
        message := &InMemMessage{Data: "hello", Ret: retPipe}

        err := w.Send(message)
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
        }
        msg := &InMemMessage{}
        err = ret.Receive(msg)
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
        }

        if msg.Data != "this better not crash" {
            t.Fatalf("%#v", msg)
        }

    }
    server := func(t *testing.T, r Receiver) {
        msg := &InMemMessage{}
        err := r.Receive(msg)
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
        }

        if msg.Data != "hello" {
            t.Fatalf("Wrong message:\n\tExpected: %s\n\tActual: %s", "hello", msg.Data)
        }
        if msg.Ret == nil {
            t.Fatal("Message Ret is nil")
        }

        message := &InMemMessage{Data: "this better not crash"}
        if err := msg.Ret.Send(message); err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
    SpawnPipeTestRoutines(t, client, server)

}
```

`SpawnPipeTestRoutines()` executes the client and server functions. In this function, another sender/receiver pair is instantiated via `Pipe()`.

**In the demo application, the function being performed here by `Pipe()` (i.e. facilitating communication between the client and server instances) is instead handled via network communications.**

```
func SpawnPipeTestRoutines(t *testing.T, s SendTestRoutine, r ReceiveTestRoutine) {
    end1 := make(chan bool)
    end2 := make(chan bool)

    receiver, sender := Pipe()

    go func() {
        defer close(end1)
        s(t, sender)
        err := sender.Close()
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("Error closing sender: %s", err)
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        defer close(end2)
        r(t, receiver)
    }()
    ...
```

In the demo application, the communication is facilitated by calls to [Transport.NewSendChannel()](https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/libchan/spdy#Transport.NewSendChannel) on the client and [Transport.WaitReceiveChannel()](https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/libchan/spdy#Transport.WaitReceiveChannel), which return a `libchan.Sender` and `libchan.Receiver` respectively. These libchan instances handle facilitating the "pipe" via the network.

From client.go:

```
sender, err := transport.NewSendChannel()
...
err = sender.Send(command)
```

From server.go:

```
receiver, err := t.WaitReceiveChannel()
...
err := receiver.Receive(command)
```

In both cases, the prerequisite transport configuration is done beforehand (i.e. binding to sockets, utilizing TLS, etc.).

It's probably also worth noting that [the spdy library being used is part of the libchan distribution](https://github.com/docker/libchan/tree/master/spdy), hence it providing libchan primitives.

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding how the pipe can span the network. what are `receiver` and `sender` in your last example if not in-memory channels? Also, `end1` and `end2` dont seem to be doing anything.

Comment: My question is specifically related to this line in your `ReceiveTestRoutine`: `if err := msg.Ret.Send(message); err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
        }` how can the `Ret` send if its being stored inmemory on the client? The client and server machines will not share memory in real life.

Comment: Added a bit more clarification at the end to illustrate the parallel to the unit test. As you point out, there's no shared memory involved. It's just a pair of `libchan.Sender`/`libchan.Receiver`, just like you get from `Pipe()`. The difference being the network transport in-between instead of the in-memory channel utilized in the unit test.

Comment: Also, my snippet from `inmem_test.go` does not include the whole `SpawnPipeTestRoutines()` implementation, just the part necessary for the communications explanation. `end1` and `end2` end up being used to verify that the client and server functions complete without any test failures.